# Very long SQL connection opening time

Tags: oracle

Recently, We have migrated our Oracle 9.2.0.6 production database from Windows 32bit RAC (2 nodes) to Linux 64 bit environment. Linux 64 bit environment has 8 times more memory than Windows 32 bit environment and Linux 64 bit has faster disk ( RAID 10 compare to RAID 5 of windows).

However, after this migration, we have noticed sql connection time has been increased significantly. Some time, it is taking 16 seconds to open a connection. We have used different driver (JDBC, ODBC, OCI) and SQLPlus. But, we have noticed no difference in sql connection time. We have investigated network, but noticed no problem with network.

Some time, it is taking around 16 seconds to open a single connection. This database has around 50000 user schema.

Can anybody tell me what can be done to reduce the connection opening time? Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: serverfault.com would be a better place to ask, and a better place to find an answer

Comment: I have similar problem, and find solutio[http://oracleprof.blogspot.com/2009/08/slow-network-connection-w-11g.html](http://oracleprof.blogspot.com/2009/08/slow-network-connection-w-11g.html)n in

Answer (score 4):

I also experienced very slow connection establishments with SQL Developer 4.1.5.21 on Mac OS against Oracle 12.1.0.2.0.

To analyze this I installed [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/intel-macsoft-096467.html) to check connectivity directly with `sqlplus`. When I tried to connect with `sqlplus` it gave me the following error:

```
$ sqlplus <USER>/<PASSWORD>@<HOST>:<PORT>/<SERVICE>
SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Thu Mar 16 10:50:44 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-21561: OID generation failed
```

I then found blog entry [Oracle ORA-21561 : OID generation failed](https://oracledbamasters.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/oracle-ora-21561-oid-generation-failed/) and added the hostname (as returned by the `hostname` command) to the `127.0.0.1`-line in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost MacBook-Pro.local
```

This fixed the ORA-21561 error in `sqlplus` as well as the slow connection establishment in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 3):

if suddenly the tnsping is become very slow(means it's a all right system before), but ping to the same *database server* is fast, The most possible reason is the listener.log file is too large:

> $ORACLE_HOME/network/log/listener.log

Some OS (SunOS in my experience) will meet writing to a very large text file performance issue(exceed 4G?), so tail/clean the log file will immediately solve the tnsping takes very long time problem.

Answer (score 3):

It was DNS in our case. After our admin commented out all DNS entries on the side of the server the system started responding without delay.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible reasons for this, and without more information its difficult to determine the root cause.

Having said that, check your sqlnet.ora file located on the machine your connecting from (i.e. <oracle_home>/network/admin/sqlnet.ora) and see if you have a line such as:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

If so, try changing it to:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)
```

Save and retry your connection via SQLPlus.

Also, check the value you have set for `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH`.  Make sure the method you're using to connect to your instance is the first in the list.  For example, we use TNSNAMES and ours reads:

```
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: For TCP connections with Net*8, the server needs to be able to resolve hostnames and IP addresses.  The fastest name resolution is a lookup in /etc/hosts file on the server.  (Name resolution is influenced by /etc/resolv.conf)

Comment: sqlnet.ora has the setting of 
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE) 
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES)

We are able to reproduce with problem from different machine with different driver. We are also able to reproduce from SQLPLUS. Network latency is not an issue. This slowness happens randomly. However, we could correlate this slowness with CPU spikes.At the time of slow connection, CPU spikes to 100%. We have also noticed that R value of the system crosses number of CPU. Which indicates CPU bottleneck.

Answer (score 1):

Things that might indicate problem areas:

From the client:

- are all clients exhibiting the problem?
- is ping *server* reasonably fast?
- is tnsping *dbname* slow?
- can you connect normally with telnet?

From the server:

- is ping *client* reasonably fast?
- is nslookup of client by name and IP fast?
- is tnsping *dbname* slow?
- is sqlplus user@dbname fast or slow?
- is a direct connection on server fast? I.E., export ORACLE_SID=db;sqlplus user/pw

Comment: Yes, all types of clients exhibit the problem. Ping is very fast. tnsping is not slow. Yes, we can normally connect using telnet. 
Ping to the client is also very fast
Slowness occurs randomly. Some how, we have noticed when around 30 to 40 connects are open simultaneously, then database CPU spikes to 100% and the connections are slowed down.