# ConnectionPool takes long time to create connection on Oracle using OCCI

Tags: oracle

I have Oracle 11g2 on RedHat 5, with default installation of Oracle.

When I run the following test program, it takes up to 30 seconds to get a connection from the connection pool. The connection pool itself is created immediately. Subsequent createConnection calls from the same pool within the same program also take similar long times to complete.

If instead I try to get a connection directly, i.e., without using a connection pool, I get a connection without delay.

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <occi.h>  
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(){

  oracle::occi::Environment* environment;  
  oracle::occi::Connection *con;  
  oracle::occi::Statement* stmt;  
  oracle::occi::ResultSet* res;  
  oracle::occi::ConnectionPool* connPool;  

  try{  

    environment = oracle::occi::Environment::createEnvironment(oracle::occi::Environment::DEFAULT);  
    connPool = environment->createConnectionPool("hr", "abcabc", "", 3, 5, 2);  
    con = connPool->createConnection("hr", "abcabc");  

    connPool->terminateConnection(con);  
    environment->terminateConnectionPool(connPool);  
  }  

  catch(oracle::occi::SQLException &e){  
    std::cout << e.what();  
  }  

  return 0;  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue with a client machine running Oracle rpm based client on RH 6.3. I changed the sqlnet.ora file in $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin with the following values

> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)
>
> SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NONE)

I restarted my program and connection problem was solved.

reference:
[Very long SQL connection opening time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364588/very-long-sql-connection-opening-time)