# ODP.Net OracleConnection.Open cold start very slow

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I have a WebAPI service which connects to an Oracle database using `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll`.  Each time after a reset of the application pool (or a deployment) there is a long delay on the first `OracleConnection.Open()` statement.  It's typically around 8 seconds.  Subsequent calls are around ~0.5 seconds each.

After reading lots of suggestions regarding server OS and networking issues, i have narrowed it down to the oracle client itself.  If I remote debug my code, set a breakpoint on the open statement, and then run Sysinternals Process Monitor i can confirm that the first open statement produces 544 entries, second and subsequent tests produce 2 entries.

The entries are quite random, but mostly relate to Cryptography.  A quick overview of the logs:

- RegOpenKey, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types\Type 001
- RegOpenKey, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider\Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider
- RegSetInfoKey, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Bryptography\MachineGuid

These are repeated several times, then there are sections like below:

- RegQueryValue, HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\WinSock2\Parameters\Protocol_Catalog9
- RegCreateKey, HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
- RegCreateKey, HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DnsCache\Parameters
- RegOpenKey, HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient

Then there are several reads of the machine.config file followed by multiple TCP connect and receive to the oracle port 1521.  Following this is a section reading the time zone from the registry.

My question is, why is the oracle client doing all of this at first open?  Is there any way i can predetermine the answer to some of these questions? (like configure the time zone so it doesn't have to 'ask' Oracle for it)?

Comment: even when there's lot of registry entries to read, that should never amount to something like 8 seconds... are there significant delays between some of the reads? security certificate chain stuff with internet access involved? I would have guessed that it has more to do with the oracle server components starting up... you explain that you have ruled that our already, still, is it a development instance with you as the only user? anything non-default configured around pooling?

Comment: I have measured all other operations - this is the most significant lag i could find - there are others to pinpoint after this one :(  It is a single user environment, no connection pooling - straight connect, one select statement, one result (4 columns or so) - very straightforward

Comment: with regard to cryptography/authentication, have a try with the last answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2364588/very-long-sql-connection-opening-time.

Comment: Even 0.5 seconds seems excessive for subsequent calls to `Open`, assuming it's pooling connections.

Comment: Its running on a server in the US, and I am calling from the UK - pings are not the greatest

Answer (score 0):

Only time I have seen something like this was when the address in the tns connect descriptor was not fully qualified, ie host=computername, instead of host=computername.domain.com.

Issue is likely dns resolution as it goes thru suffixes.  I imagine you could put in an ip and eliminate dns altogether as a test.  Consider posting your tns entry and connection string as well.

FYI, a lot of things are happening when that first connection is created, ie the pool is established and connections are actually opened vs just fetched from the pool, initial parameters for self-tuning are initialized, etc, so i think number of reg reads is probably a red hearing.